# How to run Android application to run with root privileges

Tags: android, root

How does one get an Android application to run with root privileges on a rooted device?

I've tried launching the main activity via

`adb shell`

`su`

`am start -n com.package.name/.activityName`

However when running `top` the user name running the application is not `root` as I would have expected. Note that running a standalone native and non-Android application on the device works just fine. The issue is with running an Android application as root, this is needed to make system calls that require root privilege. The system calls need to be made from native code vs. Kotlin or Java.